# Twitter streaming seems to have a latency of one tweet always

Tags: twitter, streaming, twython

There seems to be a latency of one tweet when streaming from twitter.

### Scenario

- Start the streaming with a track parameter, say "oopsnotworking"
- Tweet a tweet containing the "oopsnotworking"
- The stream does not seem to pick it up
- Tweet another tweet containing the "oopsnotworking"
- The stream now picks up the first tweet
- continue

This seems to happen to be for over a week, since I started working on streaming API. At first I thought the API is having a issue during that time, but I have heard that any issues with the API seem to get resolved within hours.

So is this how it is supposed to work?

I am using Twython btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the latency. Let me answer it myself.

There seems to be some problem with Twython, I did not look up the internals but I am pretty sure it is with Twython because when I started using Tweepy everything works fine.
I am guessing Twython is opening multiple connection caused a bottleneck, once again I haven't looked up the internal so I am not really sure what is going on with Twython.